# Convertir int to byte swift 2.3

Tags: swift2

tengo un arreglo de int lo quiero pasar a arreglo de bytes, como podria hacerlo, ya sea para swift 2.3 o objetive-c

```
let constant : [Int] = [0xC0, 0xC0, 0xC0, 0xC0, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xC0, 0xC0, 0xC0, 0xC0, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00];
```

Quiero convertirlo en

```
let constant2 : [UInt8] = [.......]
```

No importa si es todo de un golpe, o de posicion por posicion , es decir, sacar el valor de 0xC0 y pasarlo a byte y meterlo en la posicion del arreglo.
Pero no se como.

un ejemplo en java tendria este resultado

```
//[Int] swift es un array de enteros
[192, 192, 192, 192, 0, 0, 0, 0, 192, 192, 192, 192, 0, 0, 0, 0]
//[UInt] swift es un array de bytes solo que en java es diferente pero algo asi quiero hacer.
[-64, -64, -64, -64, 0, 0, 0, 0, -64, -64, -64, -64, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Comment: quieres que todos los elementos 192 se conviertan en -64 y los 0 sigan siendo 0?

Comment: Quieres que los valores del arreglo de int se trunquen o convertirlos tambien? Ya que el largo del arreglo int convertido a uint8 debiera multiplicarse por 4 (4 byte = 1 int)

Comment: Pues que es lo que no se, por que en java, si existen los -64 pero en swift creo que no, creo que es enteros igual el arreglo de bytes,  entonces no se como quedaria esa conversion a swift

Comment: pero si la idea es que se conserven los 0 osea tal como esta el array solo cambiar las posiciones que tiene valor por el valor que le corresponda. y no se como eso es lo que quiero hacer jaja

Comment: Ya creo que tengo la respuesta por si alguien le interesa.

Un array de ints, es lo mismo que un array de bytes en swift 2.3 es decir 
let enteros : [Int] = [0xC0,0,0,0xC0];
es igual que
let misbytes : [UInt8] = [192,0,0,0,192];

Es decir es exactamente lo mismo en swift.. en java si cambia en swift es lo mismo, lo comprobe sacando su valor hexadeciamal y es el mismo tanto en java como swift.

Answer (score 0):

Buen día, en Objective-C puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
int len = sizeof(int);
for (int val in array) {
    char* bytes = (char*) &val;

    //Agregas al nuevo array 
}
```

Primero obtienes el tamaño del `int` para saber cuantos `char` son y después conviertes cada valor del array y lo agregas al nuevo array de `chars`.